# ¿porque no puede instalar dos .APK en mi teléfono? o como puedo cambiar el nombre de paquete

Tags: android

Intento instalar dos apks en mi teléfono, estoy obteniendo un error cuando intento instalar al segundo apk.

El primer apk fue instalado correctamente pero el segundo me da error. Creo que esto es porque el primer proyecto fue desarrollado haciendo una copia del primero, es decir, al proyecto uno lo copie y lo renombre y de ahí desarrolle mi segunda aplicación. Entonces parece ser que el segundo apk o la configuración que tiene apunta al primer proyecto ya que fue una copia del mismo.

¿Entonces como hago para diferenciar esto para poder instalar mis dos apk?. Tal vez haya un código interno que ambos apk lo tienen.

Comment: es posible que si los dos proyectos tienen el mismo nombre de paquete no te deje instalar los dos, o el  'applicationId "com.example"'

Comment: Debes cambiar el packageName en el manifest, esta al principio es un arributo llamado package  del elemento manifest. son valores unicos tanto en el telefono como en el google play. Saludos

Comment: Hey einarcito, como comenta rnd dos aplicaciones con el mismo packagename no pueden coexistir en el mismo dispositivo, el nombre del proyecto puede ser el mismo pero tiene que ser diferente packageName.

Answer (score 4):

Solo debes cambiar el nombre del paquete a tu app para poder instalarla sin problemas.

Paso 1:
[image: Cambiar Nombre Paquete]

Paso 2:
[image: Cambiar Nombre Paquete Android]

Paso 3:
Busca buid.gradle y ahí edita también el nombre del paquete, espero te haya ayudado.

Comment: Respuestas como estas son las que yo voto a favor (te di mi voto). Cuando estoy en busca de una respuesta, a donde primero voy es a las imágenes ya que ilustran mejor lo que se intenta explicar y es más agradable a la vista del lector, de manera que ayudan más a entender.

Comment: Así es, como dice el dicho, una imagen vale más que mil palabras.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/29092698/250260 edite la respuesta aquí, ya que al Refactorizar debe cambiar automàticamente el Manifest.xml y el build.gradle de la aplicación.

Answer (score 3):

Con renombrar el proyecto no es suficiente, si tiene definido el mismo nombre de paquete (package name), no te permitirá instalar otro .apk, por ejemplo si tienes este nombre de paquete:

```
com.mipaquete.aplicacion
```

e intentas instalar otra aplicación con este mismo nombre de paquete, el sistema operativo no lo permitirá.

Puedes refactorizar momentáneamente tu nombre de paquete para crear otra aplicación, revisar el cambio también en el `AndroidManifest.xml` (`package`) y en `build.gradle` (`applicationId`), por ejemplo.

```
com.mipaquete.aplicacion2
```

Con esto podrás tener ambas aplicaciones en tu celular, pero con nombre de paquete diferente lo cual no sería visible al usuario.

#### El procedimiento para renombrar el paquete de tu aplicación o refactorizar un paquete es:

a) en tu proyecto selecciona el "engrane" y des-selecciona la opción `"Compact Empty Middle Packages"`, esto es importante para que puedas seleccionar un directorio el cual deseas refactorizar.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Posteriormente seleccionamos el folder a refactorizar, con botón derecho accedemos al menú contextual, seleccionamos la opción **`Refactor`** y **`Rename`**.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Te preguntará si deseas refactorizar el Paquete, lo cual deseamos:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

se mostrará una ventana donde se encuentran las coincidencias, simplemente tienes que dar click en el botón **`"Do Refactor"`**:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

**No es necesario realizar cambios en el AndroidManifest.xml o el build.gradle ya que la refactorización se realiza en todo el proyecto.**

Answer (score 1):

Esto ocurre cuando tratas de buildear una nueva apk con paquetes de otro proyecto , desinstalando la app en cuestion e instalando la nueva deberia corregir el problema.

PD: estas tratando de sobrescribir un paquete instalando el mismo con otro, no se si me explico, pero te pongo un ejemplo, si yo creo una app desde mi ordenador con un paquete x y yo te paso el mismo proyecto pero vos lo compilas con el paquete y , al instalar los dos tenes un problema, ya que cuando instalas el primero se instala correctamente, pero cuando queres instalar el segundo te dice que ya hay otra app corriende con otro paquete, entonces tienes que eliminar esa app para poder instalar la tuya, una vez que la instalas ya si compilas de nuevo con el mismo paquete solo se actualizara la app

Comment: Perdon creo que no especifique algo. Necesito tener las dos apks instaladas por son dos proyectos diferentes. Hacen cosas diferentes, pero erroneamente la segunda apk fue desarrollada haciendo un clon del primer proyecto.

Comment: Ese es el problema que te estoy diciendo, al tener 2 iguales , o 1 clonada, si la app esta ya subida al store, no hay forma que puedas hacer anda la otra, ya que cuando se buildea , acordate que se buildea con una key, esa key es unica, entonces si tratas de buildear tu app con otra key ya no te va a dejar

pd: en el builder trataste de cambiar el nombre de app-release por otro y fijarte que pasa ?

Comment: molesta que algunos no respeten la respuesta de los demas y las puntuen para abajo, asi da menos ganas de seguir ayudando a la comunidad :(

Comment: Cambia esa cara Armando, es importante aportes a la comunidad! =)