# ¿Cómo cambiar nombre de paquete en Android Studio?

Tags: android, android-studio

Le he cambiado el nombre de paquete a mi proyecto, sé que esto es fundamental a la hora de subir  la aplicación a play store, ya que luego de publicada una app en la play store no podré cambiar este nombre de paquete.

La duda que tengo es que aunque ya cambié el nombre del paquete, aún en los ficheros java sigue apareciendo el antiguo nombre pero en el build.gradle nivel app se muestra applicationId con el nuevo nombre.

¿Que debo hacer para que cambie el antiguo nombre en todos los archivos?, a continuación muestro una fracción de build.gradle y tambien el main activity pues allí sigue apareciendo el antiguo nombre ¿es necesario cambiar el nombre manualmente en todos los archivos?

[image: Nuevo nombre]

```
android {
compileSdkVersion 26
buildToolsVersion '26.0.2'
defaultConfig {
    applicationId 'com.uniagustiniana.tecnologias.uniagustapp'
    minSdkVersion 21
    targetSdkVersion 26
    versionCode 1
    versionName '1'
    multiDexEnabled true
    testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
}
buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
}
productFlavors {
}
}
```

Como sigue apareciendo en los demás archivos:

```
package com.tecnologias.uniagustapp;
```

Comment: Ivan, revisa estas publicaciones relacionadas en el sitio: https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/122917/cambiar-el-nombre-al-paquete-de-mi-proyecto-en-android-studio Otra pregunta similar https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/23778/porque-no-puede-instalar-dos-apk-en-mi-tel%C3%A9fono-o-como-puedo-cambiar-el-nombr/23812#23812 Aunque ambas no están marcadas con alguna respuesta aceptada =(.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

#### El procedimiento para renombrar el paquete de tu aplicación o refactorizar un paquete es:

a) en tu proyecto selecciona el "engrane" y des-selecciona la opción `"Compact Empty Middle Packages"`, esto es importante para que puedas seleccionar un directorio el cual deseas refactorizar.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Posteriormente seleccionamos el folder a refactorizar, con botón derecho accedemos al menú contextual, seleccionamos la opción **`Refactor`** y **`Rename`**.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Te preguntará si deseas refactorizar el Paquete, lo cual deseamos:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

se mostrará una ventana donde se encuentran las coincidencias, simplemente tienes que dar click en el botón **`"Do Refactor"`**:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

**No es necesario realizar cambios en el AndroidManifest.xml o el build.gradle ya que la refactorización se realiza en todo el proyecto.**

Comment: Gracias Jorge, en el caso de que el nombre anterior era de tres segmentos y el nuevo de cuatro, com.tecnologias.uniagustapp y ahora es com.uniagustiniana.tecnologias.uniagustapp, puedo agregar ese segmento.

Comment: claro,  incluso toda la estructura de archivos que esta especificada por el paquete cambiaría de com/tecnologias/uniagustapp/ a com/uniagustiniana/tecnologias/uniagustapp/

Comment: Muchísimas gracias.

Comment: @IvanAlfredo un placer Ivan!, saludos.

Comment: @Jorgesys Tengo una duda... ¿Cuál es realmente la diferencia con mi respuesta? ¿No son exactamente los mismos pasos? Te lo digo totalmente desde la ignorancia ya que puede que me esté perdiendo algo.

Comment: había una respuesta relacionada aquí pero no estaba marcada como aceptada: https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/23778/porque-no-puede-instalar-dos-apk-en-mi-tel%C3%A9fono-o-como-puedo-cambiar-el-nombr/23812#23812

Comment: @Jorgesys No vi que estaba la otra pregunta. La verdad que, en mi opinión, esta está mucho mejor redactada y la pregunta es mucho más clara y concisa. Aunque no entiendo tu comentario en mi respuesta sobre que solo puede afectar al último segmento del paquete...

Comment: gracias Elena exelente respuest

Answer (score 3):

Por suerte, con Android Studio no tendrás que cambiar manualmente el nombre del paquete tu proyecto en todos los archivos.

**1.-** Para ello, lo primero que tendrás que hacer será seleccionar paquete del proyecto en el que te encuentras y desmarcar la opción `Compact Empty Middle Packages` que encontrarás en la rueda de configuración que hay justo encima de la estructura del proyecto.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

**2.-** Una vez hecho esto, podrás observar que el nombre de tu paquete se ha dividido en paquetes más pequeños. Tendrás que seleccionar el paquete al que le quieres cambiar de nombre, darle botón derecho y, sobre el menú contextual, darle a `Refactor > Rename...`

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

**3.-** A continuación te aparecerá un Warning indicándote todos los ficheros que van a ser afectados y si quieres renombrar el paquete o el directorio. Selecciona `Rename Package`.

**4.-** Te dejará indicar el nuevo nombre que quieres para tu paquete.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

**5.-** Te aparecerá una pantalla en la parte inferior de Android Studio indicándote todos los ficheros en los que se va a modificar el nombre del paquete. Esto te permite revisar por si hubiera algún sitio donde no lo quisieras cambiar. Sin embargo, ya que es el nombre del paquete, creo que te convendría renombrarlo en todas las ocurrencias del proyecto.

Cuando estés convencido de que ya tienes todo revisado y que quieres realizar la modificación, puedes proceder a darle al botón `Do refactor`.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

**6.-** Por último, te aparecerá un mensaje indicándote que el gradle ha sido modificado desde la última sincronización del proyecto. Tendremos que darle a `Sync Now` para que se sincronice el proyecto y no nos de problemas posteriormente.

En la imagen siguiente puedes observar que el nombre del paquete ya se ha cambiado.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Y ya tendrías el nombre de tu paquete cambiado en todo el proyecto de Android Studio. Simplemente vuelve a seleccionar la opción `Compact Empty Middle Packages` para dejar el paquete compacto (como está por defecto) y... ¡¡listo!!.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Esto únicamente funciona para el último segmento del paquete.

Comment: @Jorgesys ¿A que te refieres con el último segmento del paquete? Tu puedes modificar cada segmento del paquete a tu gusto y modificará en el resto de ficheros.

Answer (score 1):

He probado ambas formas de hacerlo y en mi caso cambiaba el nombre del paquete, sin embargo al subir el archivo .abb en la play store me seguía mostrando un aviso de que debía de cambiar el nombre del paquete. Lo he solucionado haciendo click derecho en el modulo app con la vista en modo "Android", click en "open module settings", apartado "modules", pestaña "default config" y cambiando ahí el valor de "aplicationid" al nuevo nombre de paquete. Espero que a alguien le sirva de ayuda.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Pero esto no cambia los directorios, continuarás teniendo un error.