# Error al crear apk android studio despues de cambiar nombre de paquete

Tags: android

Holas , tengo este error . Luego de cambiar nombre de paquete del proyecto me aparece estos errores al intentar crear apk

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 0):

Debes cambiar el "package name" también dentro del archivo `build.gradle` esto en `applicationId` :

```
android {
...
defaultConfig {
    applicationId 'com.artemisa.linterna.gratis'
    ...
        }
}
```

Te sugiero "refactorizar" el nombre de paquete para evitar este tipo de problemas, revisa:

[¿Cómo cambiar nombre de paquete en Android Studio?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/134571/c%C3%B3mo-cambiar-nombre-de-paquete-en-android-studio)

Comment: el cambio en el build gradle id fue realizado

Comment: le di a rebuid proyect y ya puedo firmar apk . parece que solo eso faltaba

Comment: Excelente pau, si te ayudo a responder tu pregunta puedes marcarla como aceptada respuesta, te invito a realizar el [tour] del sitio. También revisa [ask] para que obtengas buenas respuestas en el sitio, saludos!