# Cambiar Id de Proyecto en Android Studio

Tags: java, android, kotlin, apk

Buen dia a todos, estoy desarrollando una app en Android, mi duda es, que si en muchas ocasiones por motivos X tengo que cambiar el Id de la app que muestro en la imagen:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Tiene algo que ver con la estructura del proyecto en caso mio de la siguiente manera:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

En si es una app para instituciones educativas que tengo que proporcionar a cada institución una app en Android, se que al crear la app, el Id de la aplicación se genera a partir de la estructura de **package´s** que tiene la aplicación, pero mi duda es que si solo cambio el Id mas no la estructura de los **package´s** tendría algun inconveniente al compilar las aplicaciones?? tiene algo que ver el Id con los **package´s**. Si alguien me podría guiar, soy nuevo en Android. Gracias de antemano...

Answer (score 1):

Si cambias únicamente el `applicationId` puede funcionar tu aplicación, pero lo recomendable es cambiar la estructura de directorios en tu proyecto para que el acceso a recursos no llegue a tener problema, es recomendable refactorizar todo para cambiar el paquete en el `AndroidManifest.xml` y cuando haces uso de `tools:context` en los layout.

Realizalo de esta forma refactorizando los nombres de directorios:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[¿Cómo cambiar nombre de paquete en Android Studio?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/134571/c%c3%b3mo-cambiar-nombre-de-paquete-en-android-studio)