# Cómo cambiar un nombre de paque o ID de un projecto

Tags: android, apk

Necesito ayuda de como cambiar un nombre de paquete en ANDROY studio por favor ayúdeme por favor

Comment: Deberías renombrar las carpetas y modificar el Manifest.

Comment: Amigo será que nos podemos ponernos en contacto por telegram para que me ayudes te lo agradezco

Comment: Esto ya se preguntó anteriormente: https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/134571/c%c3%b3mo-cambiar-nombre-de-paquete-en-android-studio/134590#134590 . Te sugerimos agregar mayor informaciòn a tus preguntas para que obtengas buenas respuestas, revisa [ask], saludos.